# SharePoint 2013 workflow is suspended. and prompt the error "An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance."

Tags: designer-workflow

As title, 
May I Know any steps to solve the problems.
Many thanks.

> Exception:  Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the workflow instance. Exception details:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   Input at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: What is the workflow trying to do when the error is thrown?  Do other 2013 workflows run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

*Form your error message i can tell this,* **You are trying to pass the "Null" value where the field value is required. It might be occur while trying to create/update an item.**

Please try to log the each steps to find the error statement.